# Deleting data from MongoDB using MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

MEAN stack newbie here. I'm having difficulty understanding how delete works in MEAN. I'm using this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701966/mean-stack-delete-callback) and [tutorial](http://www.thelittletechie.com/2016/04/a-simple-crud-application-using-mean.html#tlt) as guides, but whenever I test it out I get an error saying the data can't be deleted. Can somebody tell me what I've been doing wrong?

Here are my codes:

**Controller JS**

```
$scope.deleteProduct = function (value, idx) {

    var this_id = value._id;

    // delete
    $http.delete('/api/products/delete:' + this_id)
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        })
}
```

**Node Server**

```
app.delete('/api/products/delete:', productController.delete);
```

**Server's "Controller"**

```
module.exports.delete = function (req, res) {
    Service.remove({
        _id: req.params._id
    }, function (err, service) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json({message: "Delete successful."});
        }
    });
}
```

This is how I understood this. Is this correct?

1. **Controller JS** gets the id to be deleted and calls $http's delete request(?), using said ID and the `/api/products/delete:`.
2. **Node Server** sees that I called '/api/products/delete:' and passes the request to **Server's Controller** to complete the request.
3. **Server's Controller** deletes the data and returns status.

Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Also, I've been seeing some posts that say `$resource` works better than `$http`. Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got a couple things wrong here.

In Express in order to use `params` you need to have something in the route that can be replaced. i.e `/api/:id` express replaces the `:id` with whatever you pass in so if you send `/api/1`, `request.params.id` is 1

So first problem is your route is

`app.delete('/api/products/delete:', productController.delete);`

tha dosen't mean anything to Express. I think you want

`app.delete('/api/products/:id', productController.delete);`

now `req.params.id` should contain the parameter you send. Note im dropping the underscore here. you could use

`app.delete('/api/products/:_id', productController.delete);` and keep the underscore if you like.

Second mistake I think is your Angular code. you have the `:` in your call it should just be

`$http.delete('/api/products/' + this_id)`

Now you're sending the route with whatever Id you are trying to delete i.e

`/api/products/1`

Now Express gets that and can map it to `/api/products/:id` and replace the id and now your controller should work. barring any other issues.

**Edit**

I'm not very familiar with Angular but I think the reason people are saying to use `$resource` is it is easier. You can directly call the different HTTP verbs directly on the objects themselves objects like 
`product.update` and `product.delete` rather than trying to craft the http calls yourself. I'm sure there is a lot more to it than that but its a feature that's built into Angular that can be leveraged. I think one of the catches is the URLs for the resources just have to be set up a specific way on the server but I believe there was a way to override them in Angular.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed explanation! So that's what the `:` stands for. :) They never really explained it in any of the resources I found. I changed my code according to your tips and they're working perfectly now. Thank you!